# Calculating time difference in Perl: which is efficient

Tags: perl

I would like to compare two dates in Perl to check there difference(days,months and so on), format of both the dates are like DD-MMM-YYYY.

I am thinking of using mktime or DateTime module in Perl. 
As the calculation will be frequent, i need efficient method.

Can you please suggest which is more efficient way out of 2 or any other for doing it in Perl.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give specific examples of your dates, and what result you would like.

Comment: What do you mean by *frequent*? Hundreds or thousands per second? You should not worry about DateTime if you call it once in a few seconds, otherwise you should write your optimized subroutine, maybe even in C/XS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mktime is a native system call which I believe should be faster than using DateTime.pm which instantiates new perl objects

Answer (score 1):

[Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece) and [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime)/[::Format::Strptime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) are efficient in that they make good use of developer time. They work correctly, are thoroughly tested, heavily used and endorsed by the community, return objects, do not suffer from the C datetime API insanities.

```
use Time::Piece qw();
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('07-May-2012', '%d-%b-%Y');
# returns object of type Time::Piece
```

---

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw();
my $dt = DateTime::Format::Strptime
    ->new(pattern => '%d-%b-%Y', locale => 'en')
    ->parse_datetime('07-May-2012');
# returns object of type DateTime
```